# Visual Studio file opener doesn't show all of the folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, isolatedstorage

I have a web application that generates some files on the fly to debug in this URI:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Company
```

[image]

When I want to open those files with visual studio, I can't see that folder!

[image]

I'm wondering why I see different folders when I open it from Visual Studio!

I tried these:

- Opening Visual Studio as Administrator didn't help.
- Giving everyone full access to the "Company" folder didn't help.
- Changing the folder's owner also didn't help.
- I opened the same folder with other applications like Notepad, and I can see all of the folders.
- I tried different versions of Visual Studio (ex: 2012, 2017) but I have the same problem.

Comment: Visual Studio is a 32-bit process.  On a 64-bit OS it is subject to the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).  A workaround is to navigate to c:\windows\sysnative instead.

Comment: @HansPassant   Thanks, That's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans said in his comment:

Visual Studio is a 32-bit process. On a 64-bit OS it is subject to the File System Redirector. A workaround is to navigate to c:\windows\sysnative instead.